# Custom SObject is locked with "Admin operation is in progress" after deployment of first portion of metadata and when trying to deploy next one

Tags: deployment, metadata, 2gp

Our project contains about 30,000 of SF artifacts.

Due to the limitation in 10,000 artifacts per deployment bundle, we've split our deployment into chunks to fit into mentioned restrictions, i.e. SObject+Apex as first chunk, SObject+Aura+LWC as second (mentioned SObject again, because some of them may have actions overwritten with aura/lwc components), Apex Tests as third etc.

The challenge we are facing now is that from time to time (roughly saying 1 out of 5 deployments) when deploying second chunk we are getting error like "Admin operation is in progress" when it tries to deploy specific custom sobject (i.e. error is always referring to the same SObject).

We are trying to understand what is causing such an error and what kind of operation is happening in background with our custom sobject. First chunk of metadata has been deployed successfully, and org is not used by anyone else at the moment of deployment (i.e. no manual intervention, no scheduled jobs etc.)

We've tried it against bare sandbox (newly created), fresh scratch org etc. - but in all cases error is still there.

It seems like deployment of first chunk is causing some system background process to be executed. And depends upon timing it may or may not collide with second chunk deployment.

Are there any ideas in general of what type of background process that can be, how to identify it and avoid from happening or postpone etc. Any help would be appreciated.

Below is snippet with error we are getting when deploying second chunk of metadata:

```
[sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress
[sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress
[sf:deploy] -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[sf:deploy] Component Failures:
[sf:deploy] 1.  objects/MyCustomObject__c.object -- Error: admin operation already in progress
[sf:deploy] -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress
[sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress
```

MyCustomObject__c has ~100 fields, is on detail side of Master-Detail relationship, includes field sets, lot's of picklists relying on global values sets, couple record types etc. But still we have other objects like that, and there are no problems with them.

P.S. And things are getting even worse when we are trying to create 2gp package from our project. This error is happening permanently on package version creation, i.e. when system is deploying our code to temporarily scratch org to validate metadata.

Comment: Sounds like you need to split your project into "modules" (self-contained or extension packages) to get them small enough to avoid the package build issue. As to the admin operation, before you said it was also happening in a bare sandbox, I was thinking perhaps sharing recalculation.

Comment: @PhilW Yep, it cannot be sharing recalculation, since no data/records are involved at all, just metadata. I.e. there should be something related to metadata artifacts alignment/syncing or whatever (mainly looking now in direction of global values sets and picklist options).

Comment: @PhilW Regarding your second point. We've already tried splitting into multiple tiny 2gp packages. As result we were able to create version for package A (just with sobjects and some schema related stuff). But then we've run into same issue when creating version of package B (which use package A as dependency) when trying to introduce new field to A__MyCustomObject__c in package B. Meaning that installation of package A into hidden system scratch org locks A__MyCustomObject__c for some reason and prevents us to extends this object from other packages.

Comment: @PhilW Would you suggest as best practices just to make package A to own "whole" A__MyCustomObject__c sobject, and introduce new fields only into this core package? That would be a bit of a restriction for us, i.e. we would need to release a new version of package A every time when package B needs a new field. We would like to limit the release scope to as little packages as possible. Currently cannot find any SF docs re "not to extend sobject from base package with new fields into extension".

Comment: Think about feature-based packages where whole objects and directly supporting/related objects/metadata plus related behaviour/automation are in the same package. This is modularization by function, not metadata type. Of course, certain features may layer on top of others, which is where extension packages can come into play.

Comment: It may make sense to raise a support case if you are unable to figure out the problem. BTW, do you have an install script (apex installer)? I guess not since you are currently working unpackaged...

Comment: Could you be suffering from [this known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001JnfoQAC)?

Comment: Do you use Finalizers in tests? See [this](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000ANXvQ).

Comment: @PhilW Nope we haven't introduced package installer script yet. And we are not using finalizers at all in our code base.

Comment: @PhilW Regarding known issue, that can be the case. But the open question is still what is causing one more deployment job to be executed. I.e. we are deploying artifacts sequentially, starting next chunk of deployment only after the previous one has succeeded. We will probably proceed with SF support case to solve the mystery) Thanks